# How to use Nuxt auth with a Django server to login with Google

Tags: django, vue.js, nuxt.js, google-authentication, nuxt-auth

I'm using nuxt-auth to handle my session based authentication, it works perfect with local strategy, but it has been a disaster trying to make it work with Google strategy, after solving a lot of issues (redirect_uri, challenge_code, etc), my current problem is that after I choose a Google account it redirects me to the defined redirect_uri and there nothing happens, nuxt auth is not calling the api endpoints to validate the session key.

I've tried with @`nuxtjs/auth ^4.9.1` and `@nuxtjs/auth-next` but none of then work.

The local strategy just calls the API method and it returns a Set-Cookie header which is applied correctly, but as I told before, the call to the API is not being done by Google strategy.

Here is my code:

nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
  ...,
  //'@nuxtjs/auth'
  '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
],
auth: {
  local: {
    endpoints: {
      login: {
        url: 'auth/login/',
        method: 'post',
        propertyName: false,
        withCredentials: true
      },
      logout: {
        url: 'auth/logout/',
        method: 'post'
      },
      user: {
        url: 'user',
        method: 'get',
        propertyName: false,
        withCredentials: true,
        autoFetch: true
      }
    },
    tokenRequired: false,
    tokenType: false,
  },
  google: {
    clientId: my_client_id,
    redirectUri: isProd ?  "example.org" : "http://localhost:3000",
    codeChallengeMethod: "",
    responseType: "token id_token",
    tokenKey: "id_token",
    endpoints: {
      token: isProd ? "example.org" : "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/google", // Is it correct to use this key?
      userInfo: isProd ? "example.org" : "http://localhost:8000/api/user",
    },
    user: {
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/user',
      method: 'get',
      propertyName: false,
      withCredentials: true,
      autoFetch: true
    }
  }
```

}

In my login component I call it with loginWith('google') and it redirects me to account selection, after that, it redirects me to `localhost:3000` and the URL has the params I need, after that it is necessary to call `/auth/google` and send the `id_token` param received from google, this is the missing step, nothing happens.

I've done another implementation where I login my users by sending an `Authorization header` (Authorization: 'Token xxxx'), it works if I try it manually, but I don't know how to make Google add that header to the request.

I don't know if maybe the problem is because I am currently using the token option inside my Google strategy endpoints, but the nuxt-auth documentation is very poor and I've not found another working key.

*PD: In my local strategy I use relative paths because I have an Axios instance with a baseURL.*

Let me know if you need additional info. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you send the token to Django if you are login with google on the nuxt side? I mean that the users' management needs to be with Django.

Comment: Google just give me the token, I send it to the backend and then it answers to me a Set-Cookie header.